# Autofill from the bottom to the top of a column by increments of 10

Tags: excel

I have about a million empty rows that I need to reverse autofill by subtracting 10 from the previous row.

**This is what my column looks like:**

-empty row-

-empty row-

-empty row-

-empty row-

240610

240620

240630

240640

240650

**What I want my column to look like:**

240570

240580

240590

240600

240610

240620

240630

240640

240650

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill first three rows (starting with the lowest number and then increments of 10). Highlight all three cells. Go go the lower right corner of the combined highlighted cells. A cross will appear there (as shown in the image below). Just drag it till the end (till as many rows as needed).
[image: Look at the lower right corner of the highlighted cells. Look for cross.]

Comment: I dont know the first three rows. I only know the last couple of rows, which is why I need to auto fill from bottom to top.

Comment: you can drag from the bottom up @dfahsjdahfsudaf

Answer (score 0):

On the cell above '240610' enter `=<cell>-10` replace  with the cell of '240610'. Then click on the cell with '240610' and hover your mouse over the bottom right corner. A black cross icon should appear, then click and drag up to the cells you want to change.